# Unable to find valid certification path to requested target from Java but can log in via browser

Tags: java, certificate, ssl-certificate

I get exception:

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

However I can successfully login on this page via browser. Does it mean I am missing some certificates in my `cacerts` file? I know how to add `.cer` file into `cacerts` but how can I download proper `.cer` file from website?

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/how-to-import-a-public-ssl-certificate-into-a-jvm-867025849.html might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did what @Karthikeyan proposed in link:

1. with `openssl` command check certificate on server
2. copy

   ```
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   < Certificate content as fetched by the command line. 
   Don't change this content, only remove what is before 
   and after the BEGIN CERTIFICATE and END CERTIFICATE. 
   That's what your Sed command is doing for you :-) >
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   ```

   into file
3. Add this file with certificate to java truststore with `keytool -import` command